# How to create a .snk file from the public key?

Tags: .net

I have a public key in text form (exported using `sn -Tp`) that I want to use with the PublicSign option, and it seems that it accepts the public key in the .snk file format only. How do I create the key file from the public key?

Comment: @Dai the only purpose of the PublicSign option is to emulate strong name signing _without_ the private key.

Comment: `sn -p` seems to be what you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool

Comment: @Charlieface it's the reverse of what I need.

Comment: @user626528 I deleted my comment, I was completely ignorant of the new `-publicSign` option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818488/what-does-publicsign-do