# Can I achieve type forwarding in .NET without modifying the "from" assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, types, .net-assembly, .net-8.0

The Problem:

We are trying to move an application from .NET Framework to .NET 8.  The application needs to consume some third-party .NET Framework assemblies, one of which uses the Framework-only class System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedMemory.

I'm wondering if there's any way for me to provide an implementation of that class that I can cause to get picked up when the third-party assembly tries to load the .NET Framework version, for which it won't find a type forward from .NET 8.

This sounds horribly insecure to me, so I suspect it's not possible.  But we're in a real pickle if it can't be done.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/type-forwarding?

Comment: Maybe you need it as NuGet package? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208262/net-standard-2-0-and-system-security-cryptography-protecteddata-protect

Comment: @Auditive, that package doesn't seem to contain ProtectedMemory, just ProtectedData.

Comment: @GSerg, yes, I've read that article.  The trick here is that I need .NET to forward a nonexistent type from System.Security.dll, which is out of my control.  I can't recompile System.Security.dll with a TypeForwardedToAttribute on that class name, which is how that article describes this all working.

Comment: Do the reverse of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13346345/11683?

Comment: ProtectedMemory is just a thin wrapper around pinvoked Windows functions, simply copy/paste from the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/dataprotection.cs,2709e417c570c108)

Comment: @HansPassant, so I have read.  Where I'm hung up is how, once I've recreated the class, to get an existing .NET Framework DLL to load that class instead of throwing a TypeInitializationException when it tries to load it from System.Security.dll in .NET 8.

Answer (score 2):

While I didn't find any way to achieve type forwarding at runtime (probably for good reason), I did come across a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/37695) where a developer was trying to replace an inbox DLL with a modified build of it, just for his application.

To sum up the GitHub conversation, you can override a system DLL in your .NET application by creating your own version with the same name and public key but a higher version number.  You then include it in your C# project as an assembly reference or NuGet package.  This adds your custom DLL to the app's .deps.json file, causing it to be loaded in preference to the lower-versioned DLL that ships with .NET.

In my case, I wanted to add two missing type forwards to System.Security.dll.  Rather than clone the entire .NET runtime repo to build a custom version from source, I used [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib) to modify the inbox assembly directly.  I have a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/adv12/ShimTest) with a full demonstration of this technique and how to incorporate it into a working .NET 8 app, but here's the code for the app that creates the modified shim DLL:

```
  using System.Reflection;
  using dnlib.DotNet;
  using TypeAttributes = dnlib.DotNet.TypeAttributes;

  string stringPath = typeof(string).Assembly.Location;
  string? dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(stringPath);
  if (dirPath == null)
  {
     return;
  }

  string securityPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, "System.Security.dll");

  var mod = ModuleDefMD.Load(securityPath);
  var classesMod = ModuleDefMD.Load(typeof(System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedMemory).Assembly.Location);
  string ns = "System.Security.Cryptography";
  var mpsTypeDef = classesMod.Types.First(t => t.Namespace == ns && t.Name == "MemoryProtectionScope");
  var pmTypeDef = classesMod.Types.First(t => t.Namespace == ns && t.Name == "ProtectedMemory");

  var impl = new AssemblyRefUser(classesMod.Assembly);
  mod.ExportedTypes.Add(new ExportedTypeUser(classesMod, mpsTypeDef.Rid, ns, "MemoryProtectionScope", TypeAttributes.Forwarder, impl));
  mod.ExportedTypes.Add(new ExportedTypeUser(classesMod, pmTypeDef.Rid, ns, "ProtectedMemory", TypeAttributes.Forwarder, impl));
  mod.Assembly.Version = new Version(5, 0, 0, 0);

  string thisLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
  string solutionPath = thisLocation.Substring(0, thisLocation.IndexOf(@"ShimBuilder\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
  mod.Write(Path.Combine(solutionPath, "System.Security.dll"));
```

I didn't have to sign the DLL because the original already had a public key, but if you need to rebuild a .NET DLL, you can use [public signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818488/what-does-publicsign-do).

The missing puzzle piece for me is [getting this all to work in a C++/CLI application](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/95607), but that probably isn't relevant for most readers of this answer.